# Can't load image from an API using React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, api

I successfully load data from the OpenDota API but somehow, the images 
are broken when I pass the image props in my Heroes.js

here is the Component where I load the API.

**HeroStats.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar";
import Heroes from "./Heroes"
import "./App.css"
import axios from "axios";

const URL = "https://api.opendota.com/api/heroStats";

class HeroStats extends Component {
    state = {
        data: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(URL)
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    data: res.data
                });
            });
    }

    render() {
        const Stats = this.state.data.map(stat => (
            <Heroes
                key={stat.id}
                id={stat.id}
                name={stat.name}
                localized_name={stat.localized_name}
                img={stat.img}
                icon={stat.icon}
                pro_win={stat.pro_win}
                pro_pick={stat.pro_pick}
                pro_ban={stat.pro_ban}

            />
        ))
        return (
            <div>
                {Stats}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default HeroStats;
```

and here where I pass my props.
**Heroes.js**

```
import React from 'react'

const Heroes = (props) => (
    <div>

        <h1>{props.localized_name}</h1>
        <img src={props.img} />
        <img src={props.icon} />
        <h1>{props.pro_win}</h1>
        <h1>{props.pro_pick}</h1>
        <h1>{props.pro_ban}</h1>
    </div>

)

export default Heroes;
```

also if I use other tag like `<h1>{props.img}</h1>` it shows the image file path. did I miss something that i should include?

Comment: what does it print in case of `<h1>{props.img}</h1>`?

Comment: `'https://api.opendota.com/'+{props.img}`

Comment: image path must be wrong. try passing full image url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the value of `img` is not the full url you need to do this

```
const Heroes = (props) => (
    <div>

        <h1>{props.localized_name}</h1>
        <img src={"https://api.opendota.com" + props.img} />
        <img src={"https://api.opendota.com" + props.icon} />
        <h1>{props.pro_win}</h1>
        <h1>{props.pro_pick}</h1>
        <h1>{props.pro_ban}</h1>
    </div>

)
```